# jQuery bug in .append with ternary `:?` operators?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, ternary-operator

using

```
var states = {
    Abbreviation: "AR",
    Name: "Arkansas"
}
```

Why will this work.

```
$.each(states, function () { 
               var o = {
                    value: this.Abbreviation,
                    text: this.Name
                }

                if (this.Abbreviation === "AR") { //hardcoded for you pleasure
                    o.selected = 'selected';
                }

                e.append(
                    $('<option/>', o)
                );    
            });
```

But not this:

```
$.each(states, function () { 
                e.append(                        
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: this.Abbreviation,
                        text: this.Name,
                        selected: (this.Abbreviation === csc.statesDDL.txt().val() ? 'selected' : '')
                    })
                );    
            });
```

Are there restrictions to .append within jquery for ternary `:?` operators?

Notes: I have a logged the output of the if statements, when running the commented out code it shows ALL options as selected, the the logs output only 1 options = true. The uncommitted out code, behaves as expected.

Comment: *"are there restrictions"* ...no. Provide enough code to reproduce this problem. As it stands now you don't have a [mcve] for anyone to be able to help with

Comment: I guess maybe you didn't notice that adding `selected: ""` to the object literal in the first example makes it behave like the second when the condition fails. The `undefined` and `""` values are distinct.

Comment: Regarding your update, `this` in the `$.each` callback is a reference to the value of the current iteration, so `this.Abbreviation` will be `undefined`, so your condition fails, and the first example gets `undefined` for `selected`, and the second gets `""`, which as noted above, are distinct values.

Comment: Also, if you correct it to do this: `this === csc.statesDDL.txt().val()`, it'll still fail if you're not in strict mode, because JS turns the primitive into an object. jQuery's atypical behavior of using `this` to reference the current item just isn't great, IMO. Instead define parameters to the callback, and use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the ternary that's the issue, it appears to be how `jQuery/HTML` is handling the empty string. `jQuery` is most likely not resolving the property to an explicit false and thus creating an element with a `"selected=''"` which the browser may just be interpreting as `"selected"` which I believe is from an old `HTML` standard that recognized that as being selected. If you make the false explicit it will work:

```
selected: (this.Abbreviation === csc.statesDDL.txt().val() ? 'selected' : false)
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to formulate my questions better next time.

Answer (score -4):

I'm guessing it is not evaluating it as

```
((this.Abbreviation === csc.statesDDL.txt().val()) ? 'selected' : '')
```

but is evaluating it as

```
(this.Abbreviation === (csc.statesDDL.txt().val() ? 'selected' : ''))
```

Comment: Equality comparison operators have higher precedence than the conditional operator.